# Maven "Missing artifact com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.29

Tags: mysql, maven, visual-studio-code

I am building an app for which i need mysql-connector-j;
Using Maven (vscode) from the mysql documentation i've learnt i need to add this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.29</version>
   </dependency>
```

but i get the errors

`"Missing artifact com.mysql:mysql-connectorj:jar:8.0.29`

`The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/home/faand/.m2/repository/com/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.29/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar'`

is there something else i should do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

For version 8.0.29 the `<groupid>` was `mysql` instead of `com.mysql`